# terraform aws_s3_bucket_notification existing bucket

Tags: terraform

I need to create a aws_s3_bucket_notification that uses existing bucket (not defined in the terraform script)

I'm trying this configuration :

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-bucket-name" {
    bucket = "account-bucket-name"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
   bucket = "${data.aws_s3_bucket.terraform-bucket-name.id}"

   lambda_function {
       lambda_function_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.something.arn}"
       events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
   }
   depends_on = ["aws_lambda_function.something", "data.aws_s3_bucket.terraform-bucket-name"]
}
```

But I have this error:

> Error putting S3 notification configuration: InvalidArgument: Unable
>   to validate the following destination configurations

Maybe "data" isn't the proper way of defining an existing bucket... 
Any help? 
Thanks!

Comment: The answer below is the right way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define it as a regular resource:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "my_bucket" {
  bucket = "terraform-bucket-name"
```

Then you have to import it into Terraform's state:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.my_bucket terraform-bucket-name
```

Afterwards, `terraform plan` will show you the differences between the real world and your code, which you should resolve. If `terraform plan` lists no changes, your code matches reality.

See the very end of the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/s3_bucket.html)..

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. Your solution is working. The problem is that I need to automate it for different environments, so I need something that I can launch more than 1 times. I can verify if the resource exists before using terraform import.

Comment: Writing some wrapper that generates the code for you? Otherwise you can try [terraforming](https://github.com/dtan4/terraforming), which can generate TF code based on existing resources.

Comment: Ok, I'll try. Thanks!

Comment: In this case, doesn'T the ```resource "aws_s3_bucket" "trigger_pipeline"```try to recreate the bucket? Because now I get an error that ```Error: Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.```

Comment: No, when you imported it, Terraform will not try to create it.