# import an existing bucket in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I wanted to create an event notification on an existing s3_bucket (which is not setup by me in this current terraform code).

I came across this answer:

[terraform aws_s3_bucket_notification existing bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868066/terraform-aws-s3-bucket-notification-existing-bucket)

so I tried this. Here, local.bucket_name is the name of the existing bucket.

notification.tf

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "trigger_pipeline" {
  bucket = local.bucket_name
}

terraform import aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline local.bucket_name
```

However, I am not sure how to use this import statement. Do I use it after the resource block? Do I use it in the beginning of the same file?

If I use it as it is, under the resource block, I get this error:

```
Invalid block definition: Either a quoted string block label or an opening brace ("{") is expected here.HCL
```

at the dot here: `aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline`

**Edit:**

So first I defined s3 resource as shown in the question above. Then I run `terraform init`. Next, I run `terraform import aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline "myoriginalbucketname"` on the CLI. However, I still get the error that:

```
Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "trigger_pipeline" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

I guess I am getting the sequence of events wrong

Comment: You use the import statement on the command line, **not** in a terraform file. After you have initialized the terraform state / backend. https://www.terraform.io/cli/import

Comment: Can you help me with the sequence? So first I defined s3 resource as shown in the question above. Then I run ```terraform init```. Next, I run ```terraform import aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline "myoriginalbucketname"```. However, I still get the error that: ```Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "trigger_pipeline" {
  # (resource arguments)
}```I guess I am getting the sequence of events wrong @luk2302

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`local.bucket_name` executes in your bash, not in TF. You have to actually provide the full name:

```
terraform import aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline "my-bucket-name"
```

Comment: Can you help me with the sequence? So first I defined s3 resource as shown in the question above. Then I run ```terraform init```. Next, I run ```terraform import aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline "myoriginalbucketname"```. However, I still get the error that: ```Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "trigger_pipeline" {
  # (resource arguments)
}```I guess I am getting the sequence of events wrong

Comment: @Jbd it must be in your root module, usually called `main.tf`. Not sure what `notification.tf` is.

Comment: had to add the module name ```terraform import module.modulename.aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline "my-bucket-name"```and it worked.

Comment: In this case, doesn'T the ```resource "aws_s3_bucket" "trigger_pipeline"```try to recreate the bucket? Because now I get an error that ```Error: Error creating S3 bucket: BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou: Your previous request to create the named bucket succeeded and you already own it.```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use **data block** here. Data Block allows to use information defined outside of Terraform which helps to execute Terraform code on an existing infrastructure resources(read more [here](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources)), in this case it's S3 Bucket.
Like *resource* block, *data* block support arguments to specify how they behave; for aws_s3_bucket it's "bucket"( read more [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/s3_bucket)).

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "trigger_pipeline" {
bucket = "local.bucket_name"
}
// use data.aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline.<attribute_reference> in script

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.trigger_pipeline.id
// your code block for Notification configuration
}
```